# Is $C^{1,\alpha}\subseteq C^{0,1}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

It is true that if $f\in C^{1,\alpha}(I)$ than $f\in C^{0,1}(I)$? 
I mean: if $f$  is bounded and differenciable with bounded and holder continuous derivative, then $f$ is bounded and lipschitz continuous? 
Here $I$ is an interval, NOT necessarily bounded. If it is bounded it is clear.

Comment: Note that if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then the Lipschitz constant of $f$ is bounded by $$ \sup |f'| + 2 \sup |f| $$ You see this by noting that if $|x-y| \leq 1$ you have $f(x) - f(y) = \int_y^x f'(s) \mathrm{d}s$ and if $|x-y| > 1$ you have that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2\sup |f|$.

Comment: Thank you. Then with your observation the answer to my question is: yes,
because the derivative is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I = \mathbb R$ and let $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f'$ is Lipschitz continuous, but $f$ is not.

Comment: You are right, but my question is not well posed: $C^{1,\alpha}$ and $C^{0,1}$ are the normed space, functions must be bounded. In these case your example doesn't work.